# Subdomain using .htaccess only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I wanted to know if it is possible to implement sub domain in a web application, only using trick in the .htaccess file? That is avoiding the following

1. editing the hosts file for the subdomain link
2. adding a vhost config for the same

Your help be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by only using an apache directives.

Comment: thought so, yet wanted to confirm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rewrite command that changes a link to a subdomain.